# My App crashes when I opening push from notification center

Tags: ios, swift, push

After delay in 5 min, when app in background my app will crash, if I open push from notification center. Google says, that I must something in  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. How I can open my app, if it in killed state already? My code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
        registerFirebase(application, launchOptions)

        return true
    }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        NSLog("[RemoteNotification] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) didReceiveRemoteNotification for iOS9: \(userInfo)")
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
            //TODO: Handle foreground notification
        } else {
            //TODO: Handle background notification
        }
    }

private func registerFirebase(_ application: UIApplication, _ launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        if let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] {
            NSLog("[RemoteNotification] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for iOS9: \(userInfo)")
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
```

Comment: there would be some error on the console. Can you provide that too?

Comment: FirebaseApp.configure()
should be in  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions fir a start